# Replace and increment the number in the filename in an Android app

Tags: java, android, file, replace, increment

Please see below (both) answers for solution.

---

I can't seem to get my logic right, and for some reason this has really got me, yet it seems (and probably is) so simple. What I'd like to do is to capture an image, and, if it exists, increment the number. I.e. photo1.jpg exists, so save new file as photo2.jpg, etc.

At the moment when I run my code, and I take a picture, "photo.jpg" is saved, then with the next capture, "photo1.jpg" is saved, then "photo11.jpg", and then "photo111.jpg", etc.

Here is my code:

```
        String photoName = "photo.jpg";
        String i = "0";
        int num = 0;

        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), photoName);

        while(photo.exists()) {             
            //photo.delete();
            num = Integer.parseInt(i);
            num++;
            String concatenatedNum = Integer.toString(num);
            StringBuffer insertNum = new StringBuffer(photoName);
            photoName = insertNum.replace(5, 5, concatenatedNum).toString();
                                //insert

            photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), photoName);
        }

        FileOutputStream fostream = null;

        try {
            fostream = new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());

            //MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), yourBitmap, yourTitle, yourDescription);

            //write jpeg to local drive
            fostream.write(jpeg[0]);
            fostream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        finally
        {
            if(fostream != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    fostream.flush();
                    fostream.close();
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

---

I've implemented the below solution, and now I only end up with 2 files no matter how many images I capture. 'photo.jpg' and 'photo1.jpg' were successfully saved, but no other image was saved. They're not even being written over. Any help?

Code now follows:

```
        String photoName = "photo.jpg";
        String i = "0";
        int num = 0;

        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), photoName);

        while(photo.exists()) {             
            //photo.delete();
            num = Integer.parseInt(i);
            num++;      
            photoName = "photo" + num + ".jpg";
            photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), photoName);
            //String concatenatedNum = Integer.toString(num);
            //StringBuffer insertNum = new StringBuffer(photoName); 

            //photoName = insertNum.insert(5, concatenatedNum).toString();

        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace your `while` loop with this:

```
   while(photo.exists()) {             
        num++;
        photoName = "photo"+num+".jpg";
        photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), photoName);
   }
```

Comment: +1. Simple and to the point. I too wanted to offer a similar solution, but you were faster )

Comment: I've implemented this, and now I only end up with 2 files no matter how many images I capture. 'photo.jpg' and 'photo1.jpg' were successfully saved, but no other image was saved. They're not even being written over. Any help? :(

Comment: As a quick debug statement, after `photoName = "photo"+num+".jpg";` add `System.out.println(photoName)` to see how the name was constructed. It's strange you're not getting the desired result, because the code that constructs the name is correct...

Comment: Thanks @informatik01, I'm a bit confused as well. 

I didn't mention before that this is an Android app.
The debugging is a bit hard as my AVD doesn't like displaying live video feed, so the only way I can test my app is on my phone. I've tried outputting Toast messages however upon displaying the Toast message, my app crashes.

When I delete photo.jpg and photo1.jpg from my directory, the pictures I had taken AFTER those two suddenly display as photo.jpg and photo1.jpg. The original two don't seem to be overwritten, yet when those two are deleted, the next two images suddenly appear... weird.

Comment: @LBran Sorry dude, hard to tell what's wrong, because I have no experience with Android development. The only thing for sure, is that the code for constructing names with the increasing number works fine. btw I corrected the title to make it more relevant.

Comment: Thanks for your help, problem is now solved! I have no idea why my code was crashing on this line: num = Integer.parseInt(i);, however upon removal things seem to work fine.

Comment: @LBran Glad it finally works for you! And you hardly needed representing an integer with String *in your case* anyways, because in Java you can easily concatenate String and integer values with plus `+`, like in `photoName = "photo" + num + ".jpg";`. P.S. No need to add "Solved" in title. If you like, you can make some update note in the *body* of the question (usually at the end). Traditionally, the green check mark is enough :-)

Answer (score 2):

For the new solution - Why do you have the following line?

```
num = Integer.parseInt(i);
```

i never changes, so num also never changes. It looks like the code will just infinitely loop. It should work if you remove that line.

Comment: ...I... I don't know. I've been stuck with this problem for the past 2 days, so have played around with the code several times. I'm guessing it's gross left overs. I've made a change to the code and app is crashing now, have commented the line out and will try as soon as I fix whatever I've done to the code to cause it to crash.

Comment: You. Are awesome. Problem solved once I removed that line! Any idea why?

Comment: What that loop is supposed to be doing is incrementing the photo file name until it finds one that doesn't exist. What it was doing, before removing that line, was setting num to 0 (parsing "i", returning 0), incrementing it, checking if it exists (it did - you had a photo1.jpg existing), then moving on to the next iteration of the loop. At this point, num is now 1, but you reset it back to 0 with the parseInt line. It therefore just repeats the same check, and so on. By removing that line, num gets increased on each iteration of the loop (so it checks for photo1, then photo2, etc)

Comment: @LBran Ah, now I see what you meant. +1 for the author, nice catch!

Comment: @LBran You can definitely update the body of your question (at the end) and point out this issue, because you have two helpful answers, and in the accepted answer this issue was not mentioned.